# Two sequences $a_{2n}=a_n+1, a_{2n+1}=a_{n}+2$ and $b_{3n}=b_n+1, b_{3n+1}=b_n+2, b_{3n+2}=b_n+3$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Let us consider two  sequences $$a_{2n}=a_n+1, a_{2n+1}=a_{n}+2, a_1=1,a_2=2$$ and  $$b_{3n}=b_n+1, b_{3n+1}=b_n+2, b_{3n+2}=b_n+3, b_1=1,b_2=2,b_3=2.$$

Prove that $a_{2^n} < b_{2^n}$ for $n>3.$

My attempts to prove it by mathematical induction were without success.

Comment: It seems to be a very hard question weakly linked to the Collatz problem.

Answer (score 2):

Write $N$ in binary (base 2).  Chop digits from the end, one at a time.  Every time, you add $1+digit$ to the final value.
So $a_n=$(number of digits) + (sum of digits)-1 in binary.
Similarly, $b_n=$(number of digits)+(sum of digits)-1 in base 3.
On the other hand, I don't know why $a_{2^n}=n+1$ would be less than $b_{2^n}$, when $2^n$ has fewer digits in base 3.

Comment: $b_{16}=b_{3\cdot5+1}=b_{5}+2=b_{3 \cdot 1+2}+2=b_1+5=6.$ So $b_{16}>a_{16}$,

Comment: I just realised how excellently insightful this is. Nice idea! For large N, we can make the argument: the digits in the base 3 representation of $2^n$ will be equidistributed. There are $n\log_3 2$ digits, which average out to $\frac{0+1+2}{3}=1$. So $b_{2^N}=(1+1)n\log_3 2-1 \approx 1.26n-1>n+1$

Comment: you wrote how to calculate  $a_n$ and $b_n$ but I asked about inequality

Comment: Sorry, I agree with Xoff that it looks very hard.